# MIPS Pipeline Hazards - Branch Delay Slot

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, cpu-pipelines, mips

I'm confused about this exercise.

We have assembly code:

```
01: ADDI $1, $0, 1000 
02: LW   $2, 0($1) 
03: BEQ  $0, $0, LABEL  
04: MULT $3, $2  
05: ADDI $2, $2, 1000 
LABEL: 
06: MFLO $4  
07: ADDI $2, $1, 5 
08: SW   $2, 0($1) 
09: NOP
```

with:
**- 6-stages Pipeline

- Branch Delay Slot

- No Bypassing**

Is this correct? 
[image]

Does the Instruction in Branch Delay Slot effect on/by the others Instructions. For example here: 
**02: LW   \$2, 0(\$1) and 04: MULT \$3, \$2** 
**04: MULT \$3, \$2 and 06: MFLO \$4**

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/), and [these hints](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/) on asking questions about exercise problems. If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there.